# Can ASIO timer `cancel()` call a spurious "success"?

Tags: timer, boost-asio

The [ASIO documentation for `basic_deadline_timer::cancel()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel/overload1.html) has the following remarks section:

> If the timer has already expired when `cancel()` is called, then the handlers for asynchronous wait operations will:
>
> - have already been invoked; or
> - have been queued for invocation in the near future.
>
> These handlers can no longer be cancelled, and therefore are ***passed an error code that indicates the successful completion of the wait operation***.

The emphasis has been added by me. Normally when you call `cancel()` on a timer, the callback is run with an error code of "operation cancelled by user". But this says there is a small chance it could actually be called with a success error code. I think it is trying to say that the following could happen:

1. Thread A calls `async_wait(myTimerHandler)` on a timer, where `myTimerHandler()` is a user callback function.
2. Thread B calls `io_context::post(cancelMyTimer)` where `cancelMyTimer()` is a user callback function. This is now queued up to be called in thread A.
3. The timer deadline expires, so ASIO queues up the timer callback handler, with a success error code. It doesn't call it yet, but it is queued up to be called in thread A.
4. ASIO gets round to calling `cancelMyTimer()` in thread A, which calls `cancel()` on the timer. But the timer already fired, and ASIO doesn't check that the handler is still queued up and not executed, so this does nothing.
5. ASIO now calls `myTimerHandler`, and doesn't check that `cancel()` was called in the meantime, and so it still passes success as the error code.

Bear in mind this example only has a single thread calling `io_context::run()`, `deadline_timer::async_wait` or `deadline_timer::cancel()`. The only thing that happened in another thread was a call to `post()`, which happened in an attempt to avoid any race conditions. Is this sequence of events possible? Or is it referring to some multithreading scenario (that seems unlikely given that timers are not thread safe)?

Context: If you have a timer that you wish to repeat periodically, then the obvious thing to do is check the error code in the callback, and set the timer again if the code is success. If the above race is possible, then it would be necessary to have a separate variable saying whether you cancelled the timer, which you update in addition to calling `cancel()`.

Comment: Similar unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988051/handling-boost-asio-timer-cancelation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you stated is correct.  So in your situation you could need a separate variable to indicate you don’t want to continue the loop.  I normally used a atomic_bool and I don’t bother posting a cancel routine, I just set the bool & call cancel from whatever thread I am on.

UPDATE:

The source for my answer is mainly experience in using ASIO for years and for understanding the asio codebase enough to fix problems and extend parts of it when required.

Yes the documentation says that the it's not thread safe between shared instances of the deadline_timer, but the documentation is not the best (what documentation is...).  If you look at the source for how the "cancel" works we can see:

Boost Asio version 1.69: boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_io_context.hpp

```
template <typename Time_Traits>
std::size_t win_iocp_io_context::cancel_timer(timer_queue<Time_Traits>& queue,
    typename timer_queue<Time_Traits>::per_timer_data& timer,
    std::size_t max_cancelled)
{
  // If the service has been shut down we silently ignore the cancellation.
  if (::InterlockedExchangeAdd(&shutdown_, 0) != 0)
    return 0;

  mutex::scoped_lock lock(dispatch_mutex_);
  op_queue<win_iocp_operation> ops;
  std::size_t n = queue.cancel_timer(timer, ops, max_cancelled);
  post_deferred_completions(ops);
  return n;
}
```

You can see that the cancel operation is guarded by a mutex lock so the "cancel" operation is thread safe.

Calling most of the other operations on deadline timer is not (in regards to calling them at the same time from multiple threads).

Also I think you are correct about the restarting of timers in quick order.  I don't normally have a use case for stopping and starting timers in that sort of fashion, so I've never needed to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. What is the source of your answer? Do you know of some official or semi-official source that clarifies? Or do you just interpret the docs the same way as me?

Comment: By the way, [the docs say](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_deadline_timer.thread_safety) that you cannot access one `deadline_timer` from multiple threads, so I don't think it is safe (in theory) to call `cancel()` in a different thread to the one doing an `async_wait()`. Also, if you allow re-starting a timer then using a bool still has a (unlikely) race condition that you get an old success completion handler after a cancel and async_wait in quick succession; you would need a counter to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a second thread to run into a situation where `basic_waitable_timer::cancel()` is invoked too late (because the timer's (completion) handler is already queued).

It's sufficient that your program executes some other asynchronous operations concurrently to the not yet resumed `basic_waitable_timer::async_wait()`. If you then only rely on `basic_waitable_timer::cancel()` for cancellation then the `cancel()` call from another asynchronous (completion) handler races with an already scheduled `async_wait()` handler:

> If the timer has already expired when cancel() is called, then the handlers for asynchronous wait operations will:
>
> - have already been invoked; or
> - **have been queued for invocation in the near future.**
>
> These handlers can no longer be cancelled, and therefore are passed an error code that indicates the successful completion of the wait operation.

([basic_waitable_timer::cancel()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/cancel/overload1.html), emphasis mine, i.e. the race condition is due to the second case)

A real-world example that is single-threaded (i.e. the program doesn't explicitly start any threads and only invokes `io_server.run()` once) and contains the described race:

```
    void Fetch_Timer::resume()
    {
      timer_.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds(1));
      timer_.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
          {
            BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
            if (ec) {
              if (ec.value() == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
                return;
              THROW_ERROR(ec);
            } else {
              print();
              resume();
            }
          });
    }
    void Fetch_Timer::stop()
    {
      print();
      timer_.cancel();
    }
```

(Source: [imapdl/copy/fetch_timer.cc](https://github.com/gsauthof/imapdl/blob/3671e2a186464bfc50f1f272e50b49f690e59619/copy/fetch_timer.cc#L65-L85))

In this example, the [obvious fix](https://github.com/gsauthof/imapdl/commit/c02bac473dd936593c302facaa4c0d97e0d7e13e) (i.e. also querying a boolean flag) doesn't even need to use any synchronization primitives (such as atomics), because the program is single-threaded. That means it executes (asynchronous) operations concurrently but not in parallel.

(FWIW, in the above example, the bug manifested itself only every 2 years or so, even under daily usage)

Comment: Great point! I mentioned threads because that's the situation I was coming up against, but you're right that actually that was a red herring. BTW a Boolean flag only works if you're sure the timer will never be restarted. Otherwise there's a still a race condition in theory where it's started again before the the old queued callback is called, which then sees `!stopped_` and calls `resume()` again, effectively giving you two running timers. But this sort of race condition is often very difficult to trigger in practice and/or harmless in any case.

Comment: BTW for any readers that did want to avoid that second race condition I just mentioned: instead of a Boolean flag, use an integer (often called "generation"). Increment that whenever you stop (yes stop, not start) the timer. Capture its current value in the lambda and pass it as a parameter to the callback, which can then compare that parameter to the value at callback time to check whether it corresponds to an old stopped timer. (Even then, you still typically want a Boolean "stopped" flag for checks outside the timer callback e.g. to avoiding starting a timer that's already active.)